# Display data from three tables without duplicates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables in a hierarchical setup.  The top table:

```
Group             ID|Title
RiskFactor        GroupID|Question
Choices           RiskFactorID|Label|Score
```

There is a one to many relation where one group will have multiple riskfactors and each riskfactor with have multiple answers and each answer will have a score.  So a query with an INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN gives the same result.

Query:

```
    SELECT        
           Groups.Title, 
           RiskFactors.Question,  
           Choices.Label, 
           Choices.Score
    FROM            
           Groups Inner JOIN
           RiskFactors ON Groups.GroupId = RiskFactors.GroupId inner JOIN
           Choices ON RiskFactors.RiskFactorId = Choices.RiskFactorId
    ORDER BY 
           Groups.groupid
```

Will produce a result like this:

```
Title                       Question                                                   Label  Score
4.1 - Employment & Finance  Is your current job in JEOPARDY?  (Describe why in notes)   Yes 3
4.1 - Employment & Finance  Is your current job in JEOPARDY?  (Describe why in notes)   Maybe   2
4.1 - Employment & Finance  Is your current job in JEOPARDY?  (Describe why in notes)   NA  1
4.1 - Employment & Finance  Is your current job in JEOPARDY?  (Describe why in notes)   No  1
4.1 - Employment & Finance  How LONG was (is) your longest FULL TIME job?   NA  1
4.1 - Employment & Finance  How LONG was (is) your longest FULL TIME job?   0-6 Months  1
4.1 - Employment & Finance  How LONG was (is) your longest FULL TIME job?   1-3 Years   1
4.1 - Employment & Finance  How LONG was (is) your longest FULL TIME job?   6-12 Months 1
4.1 - Employment & Finance  How LONG was (is) your longest FULL TIME job?   Only Part Time  1
4.1 - Employment & Finance  How LONG was (is) your longest FULL TIME job?   More than 3 Years   1
```

I would like to remove the duplicates in the title and question fields and replace them with NULL or empty values so it looks more like this:

```
TITLE                       QUESTION                                                    Label SCORE
4.1 - Employment & Finance  Is your current job in JEOPARDY?  (Describe why in notes)   Yes 3
                                                                                        Maybe   2
                                                                                        NA  1
                                                                                        No  1
                            How LONG was (is) your longest FULL TIME job?   NA  1
                                                                            0-6 Months  1
                                                                            1-3 Years   1
                                                                            6-12 Months 1
                                                                            Only Part Time  1
                                                                            More than 3 Years   1
```

I've tried using a CTE and a pivot table both without any success. I'm not a SQL developer, and I'm sure this isn't a unique problem.  How can this data in a hierarchal way?  Before I would throw it into a grid an set the grid control to remove duplicates in the columns.

Comment: This sort of task should be a function of your rendering application - trying to do it as part of the query is just making life hard for yourself.

Comment: What you are asking for can easily be done but it looks like you're trying to do the job of your presentation layer?

Comment: Normally I would do this as two separate `select`s, map them into a dictionary/hashmap on the client and use that for display

Comment: Most of the time I to push this to presentation layer, but this time, the user just needs a dump of the data to an excel file without duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible hack you can try - you haven't offered any sample data so - *disclaimer! untested* - simply use `row_number` to order within each group and use an empty string (or null or whatever) when it's not the first row of the group:

```
SELECT        
  Iif(Row_Number() over(partition by groups.title order by Groups.groupid)=1,Groups.Title,'') Title, 
  Iif(Row_Number() over(partition by groups.title, RiskFactors.question order by Groups.groupid)=1,RiskFactors.Question,'') Question, 
  Choices.Label, 
  Choices.Score
FROM            
  Groups Inner JOIN
  RiskFactors ON Groups.GroupId = RiskFactors.GroupId inner JOIN
  Choices ON RiskFactors.RiskFactorId = Choices.RiskFactorId
ORDER BY 
  Groups.groupid
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and see what happens.